# Cannot attach an object to Hibernate session

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have 3 domains with these relationships:

A hasMany [bs: B]
B belongsTo [c: C]
C

Inside a webflow I do this (simplified version):

```
flow.a = new A(stuff:stuff)
flow.a.addToBs(new B(c:C.get(1)))
flow.a.addToBs(new B(c:C.get(2)))
flow.a.addToBs(new B(c:C.get(3)))
```

and then I try to show all this information on a gsp page:

```
<g:each in="${a.bs}" var="b">
    ${b.c.someProperty}
</g:each>
```

This is where I get `LazyInitializationException`. I think I understand why (webflow serializes `flow` scope) but when I try to `attach()` all the instances of `C` they don't get attached:

```
flow.a.bs.each {
    it.c.isAttached() // returns false
    it.c.attach()
    it.c.isAttached() // returns false
}
```

Why is this? No error messages I can see... Is there any better way of doing this (I'm thinking of setting `lazy:false` for these relationships)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know Grails/Gorm/Webflow. But, I know this error from Hibernate side. It means that you are trying to read a lazy object outside the scope of a transaction. There are a few ways to solve this issue: (1) Perform all operations between "beginTransaction" and "commit". (2) Use "FetchType.EAGER". (3) Load your objects between "beginTransaction" and "commit", next you can return this loaded objects to be manipulated by another peace of code, such as your <g:each>....

Comment: I know what to do to avoid the problem (like using FetchType.EAGER)... I was wondering why `attach()` is not working.

Comment: I see what you mean now. I'm not sure if I can help since I'm not familiar with the technologies you are using. In Spring + Hibernate we use session.merge() [or session.update() in old versions of Hibernate].
However, this session comes from HibernateTemplate or any sort of SessionFactory...

Comment: There is a `merge()` method available in Grails but it didn't help me either. That's OK, thanks for your suggestions.