# Grails GORM: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a method with the following structure:

```
public void run(){
    ... 
    for (...) { //this part works correct

        User.withTransaction {
            User user = User.findByUsername(...);

            Position pos = Position.findByName(...)
            if(pos){ ...
            } else { ...
                try{
                    pos.save(flush:true);
                    user.position = pos;
                } catch (Exception e){ ... }
            }
            ...
            try{
                user.save(flush:true, failOnError: true);
            } catch (Exception e){ ... }
        }
    }
    //this part doesn't work
    User.findAll().each {
    ...
        if (...){
            User.withTransaction{
                ...
                //here the operation fails with 
                //org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: 
                //could not initialize proxy - no Session
                if (!userDetailsMap.containsKey(it.username) 
                         && it.userStatus != blocked){
                    it.userStatus = blocked
                    it.save(flush:true) 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The exception I'm getting here is `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session` in the second part of my code. Here the `userStatus` field is a reference to a different domain class.

I tried to add `it.refresh()` and `Hibernate.initialize(it)`to the code before properties are checked, but no use. What am I doing wrong here?

upd: I tried to call the `it.attach` method before the properties are checked, but right after the method call the value of `it.attached` is `false`.

Comment: Are you calling this method in a view?

Comment: @SérgioMichels, no, this method is called by a scheduler. A task is added to a scheduler which calls the `run()` method.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't think you are doing anything 'wrong', it is just that the object got detached from the hibernate session. A couple of things I'd try:

- Attach the object back to the hibernate session calling the method [`attach()`](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/attach.html)
- Make the association between the two domain classes [non-lazy](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/lazy.html)

Comment: I've already tried to add `it.attach()` line, but with no success. Will try the second option.

Comment: What is strange here is that right after `it.attach()` is called, the `it.attached` value is false.

Comment: Making the association between domain classes non-lazy finally helped, but I think this is not the best solution possible. Still, it's the only one so far.

Comment: I ran into the same problem (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671456/cannot-attach-an-object-to-hibernate-session). Had to make the relationships non-lazy even though I'd rather `attach()` the object...

Comment: Isn't this pointed out in the manual? http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#transactionsRollbackAndTheSession

Comment: @ThomasFarvour, what I saw in the manual is that the session is cleared on *rollback*. There is nothing about session being cleared on a successful transaction. The second thing is that different objects are being referenced in different parts of the method.

Comment: You're right.  I tried this myself and was getting the exception even when the transaction was successful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact error when I was using sub domain classes into one class, if your data size is more than a page size, you would get the error `"Message: could not initialize proxy - no Session"`

By using `lazy:false`, hibernate will use the session attachment properly and will get the appropriate data displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas Farvour pointed in the right direction. The docs, 13.1.1 Transactions Rollback and the Session, suggest eager-fetching the children as the optimal solution.