# Grails startup after adding lazy false to domain class taking forever on IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, grails-orm

I was facing `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session` issue as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15947705/1291122) answer.
Then I used the second option, i.e. making association between domain classes non lazy (`lazy:false`)

But now when I try to run the app, I am waiting for about 15mins. The application does not start!!!

I am using Grails 2.2.1 on IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4.

Here is a bit of code(PoolService.groovy):

```
def removeChildFromPool(AccountToFollow accountToFollow){
    try {
        def pool=Pool.first()
        if(!pool.isAttached()){
            pool.attach()
        }
        if(!accountToFollow.isAttached()){
            accountToFollow.attach()
        }
        pool.removeFromAccountToFollow(accountToFollow)
        pool.save(flush:true)

        accountToFollow.delete(flush: true)
        return true
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false
    }
}
```

Attach above does not work and always gives false. So I modified my domain class as below(just added static constraints `lazy:false`):

```
class Pool {
    //Can be account id or name dependent on input csv format
    String poolName
    static hasMany = [accountToFollow:AccountToFollow]
    static constraints = {
        poolName nullable: false,unique: true
        accountToFollow nullable: true
    }
```

//Added Later On and this changed caused grails to not restart
        static mapping={
            accountToFollow lazy: false
        }
    }

Comment: Where were you experiencing the `LazyInitializationException` before? Can we see some code?

Comment: @rcgeorge23 added a bit of code

Comment: Check what sql statements get executed, consider tuning the fetch strategy.

Comment: @JensSchauder any ways to log the SQL being executed in background? and whats "tuning the fetch strategy"?

Comment: Where / how are you calling `removeChildFromPool`?

Comment: sure, just google sql+logging+hibernate